# Mysql Workbench Address Table Connections

Tags: mysql

I am looking on to designing a database in Mysql Workbench... in it, I want tables to handle addresses for users... For example,  a user must have a village, a parish, a sub-county, a county and a district.

The village can only exist in a parish, a parish exists in a sub-county, a sub-county exists in a county, a county is exists in a district...

I want to create 4 tables, so that as the admin registers a village, he also registers a parish, as he registers a parish, he registers a sub-county... Such that in the "User_details" table, I only have a villageID as the only Foreign key(representing a user's address)...which will mean that if I get your village, then I will know the whole address... How do I connect the tables? Thanks

Comment: Through foreign keys. Google it.

Comment: Jorge Campos... Thanks, I Googled, yes but I want to understand what the whole idea of foreign keys means?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key you will not find a better explanation, after reading that, read about joins (https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) and you most certainly will  understand everything you need to do your assignment. IF you still are not able to figure it out with this two articles you can be more specific on your question about what you didn't understand from those.

Comment: And answering your question `the whole idea of foreign keys means?` is: `to connect the tables`

Comment: Thank you Jorge... Certainly, article is the real thing... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help :)